# Is there a way to validate a YouTube video ID, while handling CORS and the not existing API?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am currently working on a simple website, which should run a random YouTube video inside an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) (`vid`):

```
<script>
        function makeid(length)
        {
            var text = "";
            var possible = "0123456789-_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

            for( var i=0; i < length; i++ )
                text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

            return text;
        }

        function validateYouTubeUrl(myID)
        {
            var videoID = myID;

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
            request.open('GET', 'http://www.youtube.com/v/'+videoID, true);
            request.send();
            request.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(request.status==200){
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        // Load a random video (by setting the source of the iframe)
        function getRandom() {
            vidId=makeid(11); // Create an ID
            while(validateYouTubeUrl(vidId)){ // If the ID is not valid,...
                vidId=makeid(11); // ... than create a new one and validate it again
            }

            document.getElementById("vid").src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+vidId;
        }
</script>
```

The problem is **`CORSE`** and the missing YouTube API. I know of the following links:

- [Javascript random youtube video autoplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128689/javascript-random-youtube-video-autoplay)
- [Random youtube video and API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36382403/random-youtube-video-and-api)
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=de
- [How do I check if a video exists on YouTube, in client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809067/how-do-i-check-if-a-video-exists-on-youtube-in-client-side)
- [Youtube iframe api check if video exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322397/youtube-iframe-api-check-if-video-exists)
- [How do I check if a video exists on YouTube, using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383073/how-do-i-check-if-a-video-exists-on-youtube-using-php)

But *most of them* are outdated and simple do not answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

try with https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos.

```
function validateYouTubeUrl(myID)
    {
        var videoID = myID;

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='+ videoID + '&key=KEY&part=snippet', true);
        request.send();

        if (request.status === 200) {
        var response = JSON.Parse(request.responseText);
            if (response.pageInfo.totalResults == 0) {
                 return false;
            } else {
                 return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        temp.pageInfo.totalResults
    }
```